# Angular: "cannot find name", element doesn't exists yet in DOM

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with Angular5, I have a little chat system.

When user send a message, a LI element is created :

`chat-component.html`

```
<li #ChatListItem *ngFor="let message of messages" class="list-group-item">
    {{message}}
</li>
```

This means on page load, `#ChatListItem` doesn't exist yet in the DOM.

I need to perform some actions on `#ChatListItem` (i.e autoscroll), so in my component I have:

`chat-component.ts`

`@ViewChildren('ChatListItem') chatListItem: QueryList<ChatListItem>;`

But when I try to compile, I got this error message :

`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ChatListItem'.`

This is still working with `ng serve` even if i have this error, but i cannot run any `ng build`.

I guess this is because `#ChatListItem` doesn't exist in the `DOM` ?
How can I manage to make this work ?

Comment: Use in `AfterViewInit` and as @Suren Srapyan points - you dont have such type. Can use `any` -   `@ViewChildren('ChatListItem') chatListItem: QueryList<any>;`

Comment: This means on page load, #ChatListItem doesn't exist yet in the DOM. Wrong. It exists, except if it's not wrapped in some conditional part. `QueryList<ChatListItem>` where you have defined this ChatListItem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your element is not of type `ChatListItem`, but it is just an `li` element. So you need to provide the type of `li` in the `QueryList`.

```
@ViewChildren('ChatListItem') chatListItem: QueryList<HTMLLIElement>
```

Comment: ofc thanks you're right, ChatListItem isn't a type... Its working with HTMLLIElement instead